# Ubuntu 18.04LTS freezes with pixelated screen

Tags: 18.04, display, ubuntu-drivers

My system randomly freezes with a screen looking like this. It happens inconsistently but a couple of times in 10 hours for sure. Below are the details. Please help with anything that can be done to fix it.

[image]

[image]

```
sudo lshw -C display

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Nothing works at this point, no keyboard commands, terminal etc.

Comment: First, make sure the system is hung as well, and not just the UI. Typically, you try to connect to this host remotely. Make sure the I/O is truly hung as well by seeing if you can get to a virtual terminal: https://superuser.com/q/100693/609232

Comment: Okay. Let me check that next time it happens. Thanks.

Comment: @jdv It happened today and I was not able to access any of the VTs. Thoughts?

Comment: Does the host respond to network traffic like pings or ssh attempts? Assuming this host is completely hung this implies hardware failure or something close to the metal, like a driver. Might be time for a memtest from the boot menu and maybe even something like "StressLinux" if that is still around.

Comment: That all being said, this is a pretty vanilla machine in terms of chipset and graphics. This implies you have some bad memory.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. How do I confirm that its bad memory? Are there any logs where I can check this?

Comment: I think Ubuntu almost always has a Grub boot option to run "memtest". If not, I think every  recent live boot image can do this. Research "memtest" and/or "StressLinux". I don't know anything about the latter, but it seems to be a thing for serious hardware testing.

Comment: Thanks. I did a memtest from Grub menu yesterday and there were 0 errors. What can be checked next?

Comment: You are going to have to research deeper. Is this new behaviour, or has it always happened? If the former, what has changed recently? Build up a tree of info like this, possible using references like https://superuser.com/q/106006/609232 https://serverfault.com/q/192149 Maybe start looking for hardware specific issues for your chipset or graphics (i.e., there are reports of certain X servers with i915 drivers hanging). Inspect the startup logs carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Let me check and will update.